# Elastic - Create multiple aliases at a time in R

Tags: r, elasticsearch

I want to create multiple aliases for an index at a time.

To create one alias for an index in R with the elastic package, I use the following code:

```
elastic::alias_create("test_index", alias = "test_alias")
```

How do I create multiple aliases at a time?

I've tried

```
elastic::alias_create("test_index", alias = ["test_alias1", "test_alias2])
```

and

```
elastic::alias_create("test_index", alias = c("test_alias1", "test_alias2"))
```

but both doesn't work. I have used the information about alias from [elastic](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html)

Comment: i'ved opened an issue about it https://github.com/ropensci/elastic/issues/230 it's not supported currently. seems we need to switch to passing the data in the body of the request instead of the URL to give more flexibility

Answer (score 0):

Please try with POST /_aliases

```
{
"actions" : [
    { "add" : { "index" : "test1", "alias" : "alias1" } },
    { "add" : { "index" : "test1", "alias" : "alias2" } }
]}
```

You can refer https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html for more.

Comment: Thank you, but how do I use this within R? I like to use the `alias_create` function from the elastic package.

Comment: Could you please explain how are you using this? Are you using HighLevelRestClient?

Comment: What do you mean by "how are you using this?. I load the package `library(elastic)`,load my connection and execute `elastic::alias_create("test_index", alias = "test_alias1")` to create one alias for the index. However, now I want to create multiple aliases at a time instead of using a for loop.